# Is it possible to get Doxygen to only regenerate information that is dependent on the changes made?

Tags: doxygen

I have a very large project and I would like it so that if a change is made, doxygen will build *only* the stuff that has changed or is dependent on the changes made to reduce the time it takes to regenerate the documentation.

I looked around the doxygen documentation and didn't seem to find any such thing but am asking to make sure that I didn't miss anything.

Comment: doxygen does not have this incremental ability. The only possibility I see is using tag files.

Comment: Tag files?  Could you elaborate @albert?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation where there is some information about tag files e.g. GENERATE_TAGFILE

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, but I think it would require too much intervention to manually set this up. :(  I have many very large projects under one visual studio solution.